# Your class has 100 students and they have 5 elective courses to choose from. In each course, the proportion of students is equal in population

Tags: self-study, central-limit-theorem, bivariate, multivariate-distribution

I am actually unable to understand the question and would appreciate it if someone can help with that. For the above problem statement, there are three questions that I need to answer

1. Make a realization of students for the 5 electives
2. What will be the distribution of students in the course if you repeat the above process n times? Can you back it using any graphical methods?
3. Use the multivariate central limit theorem and generate a bivariate density plot of the proportion of students taking the first 2 courses.

I am, as I said, simply unable to understand how to proceed with the first 2 questions.

I do not require the solutions. I can use R to solve it but just need a push in the right direction.

Comment: Welcome to CV. If this question relates to a class exercise, please see https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info and add the tag to modify the question accordingly.

Comment: Thank you, I've done the needful @Pitouille

Comment: Everything hinges on how you interpret the vague and bizarrely stated condition "the proportion of students is equal in population."  (I can imagine several possible intended meanings.)  So, begin by deciding what you think that means.  That will translate into a procedure for (1), which you can then apply to answering (2).